# How do I display only textviews that have values?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, textview

If I have 10 textviews, how do I efficiently display those that have values and hide those that don't have values without checking if they have values then set the `visibility` to `VISIBLE` for each textview. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Textviews are within a `LinearLayout`

Comment: you can check if a textview is empty or not and then set it's visibility. Is there an efficient way to check  this on all 10 textviews

Comment: Then why not check them all with an ```if``` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have a place in the code where this check happens anyway.

If you want a way to remove the boilerplate which this check generates I can suggest using kotlin extension function like this:

```kotlin
fun TextView.setTextOrGone(text: String?) {
    this.visibility = if (text.isNullOrBlank()) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    this.text = text
}
```

And then set text like this:

```kotlin
textView.setTextOrGone(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom textview that hides itself if it doesn't have any text to display.

```
public class CustomTextView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    public CustomTextView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            setVisibility(GONE);
        }else{
            setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```